# Makefile - Function to check empty environment variables

Tags: makefile

I am trying to write a function to check if multiple environment variables are set. In this example, I've just tried to use a function which does not works probably because `call` opens up a subshell which does not has my exported variable.

What is a neat way to check multiple environment variables? I am trying to avoid multiple `ifndef` statements in my `Makefile`.

#### Makefile

```
define func_test
ifndef ${1}
$(error ${1} is not set - does not works)
endif
endef

test:
    @$(call func_test, account_name)

ifndef account_name
$(error account_name is not set - works)
endif
```

#### Logs

```
~ $ export account_name=somename
~ $ make test
Makefile:8: ***  account_name is not set - does not works.  Stop.
~ $
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if variable is empty

```
$(if $(some_var),,$(error some_var is not defined))
```